# Verify Files Uploaded to S3 Via Storage Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

I'm trying to work out the best strategy for comparing checksum values in s3 with my files on local disk.

I am uploading these files via AWS Storage Gateway but I cannot find a way to attach metadata in the usual manner using the AWS CLI described in the following link.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/

I can extract the E-Tag value from s3 but how do I compare that value to the one I generate before copying the file? If I have to generate a checksum in the same manner as S3 does on upload, how do I do that?